# What does Translate Instances node do?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I searched for the function of Translate Instances geometry node on Google and only got answers from Blender official website. I don't understand what it actually does. Can somebody explain the function in non-technical way?

Comment: It moves instances https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/translate_instances.html

Answer (score 3):

It really does what it says - translates the instances. So let's say you have some instances and you want to move some of them. You need to pick the ones you want to move if you don't want to move all of them so you can use Selection input. I made an example where I instance some spheres on each point of the geometry - in this case each vertex of my default cube, then I compare their position in Z axis to 0 because let's say I want to move the ones that are higher than the floor - so 0 in Z axis. I feed the result of that comparison to Selection input and change the translation vector(X, Y and Z coordinates that I want to add to the location of my selected instances):

[image]

It is indicated by this icon:

[image]

that the Translation input of the Translate Instances node accepts [fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html) so it can get a lot more complex since you can feed it all sorts of data with ranges of values.